# REACT.JS: Npm install + npm start vs npm run build + serve -s build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When developing locally, I'm using `npm install` to install my dependencies and `npm start` to run the application.
However, when I'm preparing the app for a production environment, I'm running the command `npm run build` and after the `build` folder is created, I'm running `serve -s build`.

I can access the web but some buttons/elements have a different UI (bigger or smaller, missing border, etc) than when running with npm start.

No errors while running these commands so I don't know what is missing. any ideas?

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';



ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Are your `css` files loaded correctly? I had a similar issue and found out CSS paths are not correct in the built version (relative vs absolute paths)

Comment: I think all files path are correct. The problem appears to be only with bootstrap that is causing some conflict with the order of `css` files. I've read that I should import it on the top of `index.html` file and add everything else below it, but it's not working

Comment: So share your code

Comment: @Shahriar edited my question with the code from `index.js` file